# Can we cron schedule bash file execution in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-scheduler

Can we cron schedule `local_exec` to execute the bash file that having the multiple commands in Terraform? I tried the `[google_cloud_scheduler_job][1]`

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {
  name = "test-job"
  description = "test job"
  schedule = "*/2 * * * *"
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/bash_file.sh"
  }
}
```

But I am getting an error

```
Error: ExactlyOne

  on main.tf line 366, in resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job":
 366: resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {

"app_engine_http_target": one of
`app_engine_http_target,http_target,pubsub_target` must be specified


Error: ExactlyOne

  on main.tf line 366, in resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job":
 366: resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {

"pubsub_target": one of `app_engine_http_target,http_target,pubsub_target`
must be specified


Error: ExactlyOne

  on main.tf line 366, in resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job":
 366: resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {

"http_target": one of `app_engine_http_target,http_target,pubsub_target` must
be specified
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule `local-exec` at all, and certainly not with a Google cloud scheduler. This is not how `local-exec` works at all, or what it is intended to do. How would the Google scheduler be able to reach into your computer to locally execute a bash script?

You probably want to build whatever your bash script is doing into a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), and provision that function via Terraform.

Comment: *Mark B*, can you help me out, I am new to this technology.